# Vegan restaurants in Paris (5th arrondissement)

Tags: food-and-drink, paris, dietary-restrictions

I'm visiting Paris soon and I was trying to find vegan restaurants and bars there. I am specially interested in places around the 5th arrondissement.

Is there any list of such places? If it were also possible to see the location of the restaurants in a map it would be great.

Answer (score 4):

[Happy-cow](https://www.happycow.net/searchmap?lat=&lng=&location=Paris%2C%20France&vegan=true&vegetarian=true&vegfriendly=true&stores=true) let's you find vegetarian, vegan and veg-friendly places in Paris and a lot more cities. It shows the results in a map (allowing some interesting options as choosing just those places that are currently open) and a list ordered by distance/rating/price or some other criteria.

It also allows you to post reviews, making it easier to choose when considering different options.

Comment: Are you related somehow to that website you're promoting ?

Comment: @blackbird57 No, I'm not. I was just trying to find the information by myself today and I thought it would be interesting to have a question about it here. I posted a link to that website because it was the best answer that I found but I'm not affiliated in any terms to them.

Comment: I can't say anything about Paris, but for the few German cities I checked, Happy-cow seem to have a somewhat strange and also outdated selection of restaurants. I am not so sure what qualifies a 'veg-friendly' restaurant and which requirements must be fulfilled to be listed on their web-page. Perhaps that's why I wonder why so many good restaurants are missing. It was however easy to spot a few places, which have already been closed for quite some time, but are still listed.

Comment: French for vegan is 'véganisme' or 'végétalien' (no meat or animal related food). French for vegetarian is 'végétarien'. In case it can help to search.

Comment: @A.A. I'm coming to visit Madrid soon, how about a meetup? Sorry for writing here, you're not pingable in chat. Log into chat to discuss?

Answer (score 2):

According to La Fourchette, which is a website where you can find all the restaurants in France, the only Vegan restaurant in the 5th arrondissement of Paris is "Le Puits de Légumes".

I leave it to you to use [La Fourchette](http://www.lafourchette.com/restaurant+vegetarien+5e-arrondissement+paris?filters[TAG][restaurant_tag%7C531%7C19]=1) to find others! Around the 5th, you have the 6th, the 4th and the 13th arrondissements.